# Mongoose Model not importing in my Node.js index.js file

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a model for photos for storing photos.
I need to export the model to the index.js file but it showing the error `Module Not Found`.

Models/photo.js:

```js
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/byf',{ //connection to database
        useNewUrlParser : true,
        useCreateIndex :true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    const Photo = mongoose.model('Photo',{ //model name Photo
        path:{
     
            type : String
        },
        caption : {
            type: String
        }
    })
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Photo',photoSchema)
```

index.js:

```js
    const photo = require('./Models/photo')
```

The full error is:

```
Error: Cannot find module './Models/photo'
Require stack:
- C:\wamp64\www\Node.js\byf\src\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1028:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\Node.js\byf\src\index.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1139:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1159:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\Node.js\\byf\\src\\index.js' ]
```

Comment: there's an error in your code `photoSchema` is undefined

Comment: in `photo.js` rename `Photo` to `photoSchema ` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Comments on your question were helpful, but they didn't notice, you have already created a mongoose.model, so when you're exporting it is not exporting correctly and thus you're seeing this error.

Also, you do not have a Schema ready for your mongoose.model
I'm patching in a more appropriate approach of creating a model in the below code, kindly compare the codes and make required changes.

```js
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/byf',{ //connection to database
        useNewUrlParser : true,
        useCreateIndex :true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })


    const photoSchema = new Schema({ //model name Photo
        path:{
     
            type: String
        },
        caption : {
            type: String
        }
    })
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Photo',photoSchema) //To save yourself from the mongoose auto pluralisation use Photos as a model name
```